# Why doesn't the Gemara cite Avos as a proof?

Tags: tractate-brachot, pirke-avot-ethicsof

The Sugya in [Brachos 6a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=1&daf=6&format=text) (cited in the name of רבין בר רב אדא א"ר יצחק)

> אמר רבין בר רב אדא א"ר יצחק מנין שהקב"ה מצוי בבית הכנסת שנאמר אלהים נצב בעדת אל ומנין לעשרה שמתפללין ששכינה עמהם שנאמר אלהים נצב בעדת אל ומנין לשלשה שיושבין בדין ששכינה עמהם שנאמר בקרב אלהים ישפוט ומנין לשנים שיושבים ועוסקין בתורה ששכינה עמהם שנאמר אז נדברו יראי ה' איש אל רעהו ויקשב ה' וגו' מאי ולחושבי שמו אמר רב אשי חשב אדם לעשות מצוה ונאנס ולא עשאה מעלה עליו הכתוב כאילו עשאה ומנין שאפילו אחד שיושב ועוסק בתורה ששכינה עמו שנאמר בכל המקום אשר אזכיר את שמי אבוא אליך וברכתיך

seems vaguely reminiscent of [Avos 3:7](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/b/h/h49.htm)

> רבי חלפתא איש כפר חנניה אומר, עשרה שהיו יושבין ועוסקין בתורה--שכינה עימהן, שנאמר "אלוהים, ניצב בעדת אל" (תהילים פב,א).  ומניין שאפילו חמישה, שנאמר "ואגודתו על ארץ יסדה" (עמוס ט,ו).  ומניין שאפילו שלושה, שנאמר "בקרב אלוהים, ישפוט" (תהילים פב,א).  ומניין שאפילו שניים, שנאמר "אז נדברו יראי ה', איש אל ריעהו" (מלאכי ג,טז).  ומניין שאפילו אחד, שנאמר "בכל המקום אשר אזכיר את שמי, אבוא אליך ובירכתיך" (שמות כ,כ).

Why doesn't the Gemara cite it as a proof or support?

Comment: I like the question.  Can you put some more details in the question so we don't need to go elsewhere to find the sources you refer to?

Answer (score 4):

There are two separate angles the two sources wish to respectively address. Avot intends to list possible degrees of Divine presence, nothing more. The Talmud wishes to detail specific differences in each group, independent of the degree of presence this is why here there is more detail and the number five is missing. First, one who learns Torah, Shechinah is with him. Two who learn Torah together, God writes their words. Even if three judges are ruling, not studying Torah, Shechina is with them. And for 10, the Shechinah precedes their gathering together and is already present in the Beit Midrash.

-Maharal ([*Derech Chaim* 3:6](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=42838&st=&pgnum=171))

Answer (score 0):

The sugya in Brachos first starts talking about the shechinah being manifested by 10 while they are *davening*, in Tefillah, like it starts off "how do we know that the Holy One, blessed be He, is found in the **house of prayer** (beis hakanesses)", then afterwards, it asks regarding 3 who sit in *judgement*, and only after does it ask about 2 (and even 1) who learn *Torah*, that the shechinah is there

However, the Mishnah in Pirkei Avos is *only talking about Torah*, like it starts out "from where do we know that ten who sit and engage in *Torah*, that the Shechinah is there...",  but in Brachos, it asks about Tefillah (as mentioned), then it continues to find proof for 5, regarding Torah, then 3, regarding Torah (not judgment), then finally the proof for 2 and 1 are almost the same as Brachos

So if Brachos would bring it as a proof, it would only be a proof for the last two statements, and since the proof is the same (essentially) anyways it would make sense to simply say the verses again independently, since the rest of it is talking about different things